# "Host key does not match configured key" when connecting to SFTP server with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm having some trouble while trying to implement an SFTP connection via C#. At the moment I can connect using WinSCP with my host, port, login, password and the key file (ppk file).

My implementation is just like this using WinSCP .NET:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol              = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName              = "",
    UserName              = "",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "",
    SshPrivateKeyPath     = "",
    PrivateKeyPassphrase  = ""
};

using (Session session = new Session ())
{
    session.Open (sessionOptions);
}
```

In `session.Open` I always receive an exception. When I don't fill `SshHostKeyFingerprint` parameter I receive the following exception:

> SessionOptions.Protocol is Protocol.Sftp or Protocol.Scp, but SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint is not set.

Then I just opened my ppk file with PuTTYgen. After that I copied the "Key fingerprint" and put into my code. Now I'm receiving the following exception:

> Host key does not match configured key

Does it mean I must have this key in my server? If so, where should I put this key? In this case why can I connect via WinSCP without passing this fingerprint?

Thank you!

Comment: See also WinSCP documentation for the error message: [SessionOptions.Protocol is Protocol.Sftp or Protocol.Scp, but SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint is not set](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_sessionoptions_sshhostkeyfingerprint_is_not_set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SshHostKeyFingerprint` must be set to a fingerprint of server's public key (aka host key), not in the public key of your authentication key pair (your local ppk file). 
See [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys) article on WinSCP site.

WinSCP GUI probably works because it has a cached copy of the SSH host key from the first time you used WinSCP with this particular server.

It looks like there is some information on the WinSCP site for [how you might go about getting SshHostKeyFingerprint within .NET](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey). There is even a flag to use to skip host key verification (not secure:  you could be connecting to a different server or someone could possibly [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) the connection).